# Доступ к канвасу через JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5, canvas

Прочитал, что доступ к канвасу реализовывается так через квадратные скобки:

```
    var canvas = $("#canvas1")[0];
    var x = canvas.getContext("2d");
    x.fillRect(50, 40, 55, 55);

    /*var d = $("#div1");
    d.css("background-color", "blue");*/
```

Почему к другим элементам, например к `div`, я обращаюсь просто через `id`.
А к канвасу еще добавляются `[0]`, иначе доступ не получаю.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jqObject = $("#canvas1");              // возвращается jQuery-объект
var domElement = $("#canvas1")[0];         // возвращается DOM-элемент
var x = domElement.getContext("2d");       // JS-метод для DOM-элемента
jqObject.css("background-color", "blue")   // jQuery-метод jQuery-объекта
x.fillRect(50, 40, 55, 55);
```